# Is this logic possible?

Tags: erc-20

Lets suppose here are user A and smartcontract B and C.
A has no token but little ETH for gas, but B has enough tokens(Erc20).

1. A send TX to B
2. B send delegatecall to C
3. C receive tokens in B and give ownership to A

Is this logic possible? If not, how can I make it? Pls correct me.

Comment: Why do you need contract C? Why doesn't contract B just transfer its tokens to user A?

Comment: C is a kind of dapp. B need to send tokens to C directly to save time.

Comment: Then I don't understand the question. Maybe when you said "and give ownership to A" you're talking about ownership of something other than the tokens?

Comment: I meant "C receive tokens in B and provide service to A"

Comment: In that case, of course this is possible.

Comment: Really? Can you give me some hint?

Comment: I am stucked with msg.sender issue

Comment: I added some code. Just pass the address to C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some code doing this:

```
contract C {
    ERC20 token = ERC20(0x...);
    address ownerOfFoo;

    function buyFoo(address owner) external {
        require(ownerOfFoo == address(0), "already owned");
        require(token.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), 1000), "foo costs 1,000 token units");

        ownerOfFoo = owner;
    }
}

contract B {
    ERC20 token = ERC20(0x...);
    C c = C(0x...);

    function helpMeBuyFoo() external {
        // probably you want to allow only A to do this?
        // require(...);

        token.approve(c, 1000); // tokens will come from B
        c.buyFoo(msg.sender);   // tell C who should get the service
    }
}
```

Comment: I have question. If contract C(sort of dapp) check balance of msg.sender while executing function buyfoo, then it could be failed because there is no token in A's account. Isn't it?

Comment: If C checks the balance of `msg.sender`, it will be checking the balance of B.

Comment: Is contract B using delegatecall or just call? I am still confused.. because if it's delegatecall, msg.sender must be A I think.

Comment: It's just a regular call. `delegatecall` wouldn't make sense here.

Comment: In case of regular call, msg.sender in C must be contract B not A right? So, contract C can receives tokens from B but also gives service to B NOT A. Please correct me @smarx

Comment: contract C you coded seems like not standard. Can B does interact with any general contract? or Should B need special contract such as C?

Comment: Well, if the contract C is going to provide service to an account _other_ than the one that calls it, it will have to be designed to do that. If you're saying you have no control over the contract C, then you'd  have to look at that contract and see if it allows for such a thing.